# Can't print a field called "end" using jq

Tags: jq, keyword

I'm trying to print out a field called "end" from a json file using `jq` but am running into the following error:

```
$ echo '{"start": 10, "end": 20}` > /tmp/out.json
$ jq .start /tmp/out.json
10
$ jq .end /tmp/out.json
error: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting $end
.end
 ^^^
1 compile error
```

This issue (https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/256) suggests using `.["end"]` as the selector but that doesn't seem to work either.

```
$ jq .["end"] /tmp/out.json
error: syntax error, unexpected end
.[end]
  ^^^
1 compile error
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was fixed in more recent versions of jq. I can do this:

```
$ jq --version
jq-1.6-1-g2f2d05b
$ jq .end <<< '{"start": 10, "end": 20}'
20
```

Your second attempt failed because the shell removes the double quotes. You have to protect them by quoting the whole thing:

```
jq '.["end"]'
```

---

The relevant issue that describes your initial problem is [Reserved words should not generate errors when used as object keys](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/794); the fix was in [this commit](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/commit/11f084f9a71ac5feacb563096aa68deb57a3bc41), and it looks like it was in jq since [version 1.5rc2](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/releases/tag/jq-1.5rc2).

Comment: That was exactly it. Thanks!